# asp.net ajax postback: how to remain scroll position of a panel

Tags: asp.net

I have a panel, inside a panel there are some checkbox and radiobuttonlist. This panel is place inside an UpdatePanel ajax.

When I click on a checkbox, it will raise autopostback with ajax supported, then the scrollbar of the panel always move back to the first position. It does not keep the current scrolling position.

How could I remain the scrollbar position?

I already have tried to add:

```
this.Page.SetFocus("PanelTrips");
this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```

But it does not help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer for this, if anyone needs:

```
// ajax post back begin and end event
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
var scrollTop = 0;

function beginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

var elem = document.getElementById('divContainer');

scrollTop = elem.scrollLeft; //scrollTop

}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {

 var elem = document.getElementById('divContainer');

 elem.scrollLeft = scrollTop;

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob, but you are embedding JavaScript in your code-behind? I remember seeing a video about .NET 4, and how it is very accommodating with JS now, which is really cool.

Comment: 9 years later and this is just what I needed (and negated lots of issues with other solutions involving update panel triggers within user controls). Great solution olidev, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works by simply including the javascript on this page http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver which also contains more detailed instructions.